# How to bind a WPF ComboBox to a two dimension x:Array?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have been successfully using **x:Arrays** in Resource Dictionarys as a source for ComboBox data elements like so:

```
<x:Array x:Key="DataArray" Type="sys:String" >
    <sys:String>Data Item 1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Data Item 2</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Data Item 3</sys:String>
</x:Array>
```

I now want to use a similar method for two dimensional arrays but I get the Error -

> The name "VelocityLevels" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:RMS_EF6".

In the ResourceDictionary I have ...

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RMS_EF6">

<x:Array x:Key="VelocityArray" Type="{x:Type local:VelocityLevels}">
    <local:VelocityLevels VelocityNumber="0" VelocityName="Years"/>
    <local:VelocityLevels VelocityNumber="1" VelocityName="Months"/>
    <local:VelocityLevels VelocityNumber="3" VelocityName="Weeks"/>
</x:Array>
```

In App.xaml.cs ....

```
namespace RMS_EF6
{
    public class VelocityLevels
    {
        public int VelocityNumber { get; set; }
        public string VelocityName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the GUI ...

```
<ComboBox x:Name="add_TargetVelocityComboBox"  Grid.Column="8" Width="200" 
       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource VelocityArray}}"
       DisplayMemberPath="VelocityName"
       SelectedValuePath="VelocityNumber"
       SelectedValue="{Binding TargetVelocity, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"                                          
       Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True"/>
```

Grateful for any advise as to why the name "VelocityLevels" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:RMS_EF6"

Comment: This isn't a compile error it is a design error correct? Tried compiling your solution?

Comment: Yes general - I haven't had a clean compile yet due to other issues.  Perhaps compilation will fix it.

Comment: I did create a test project and implemented your code into <Windows.Resources> and had no errors - if you cannot compile your program due to this error, you could try moving your array declaration to Window.Resources and try again?

Comment: your problem is solved? Been a designer error?

Comment: Sorry dsdel - cant say yet.  Still working towards a compile.

Comment: Yes.  It was a design error that was squeezed out by the clean compile.

Comment: Great, Thank you for your feedback! Added this as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completition: It was a designer error (xaml designer) due to outdated object files (no clean compile since implementation in xaml happened).